# Material-UI grid change default columns

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am trying to change the default number of columns (12) on the Grid component to 16. I have some code that is nearly copy-pasted from the docs, but it still renders as 12 columns.

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

function AboutPage(props) {
    return (
        <>
        <Grid container spacing={2} columns={16}>
            <Grid item xs={8}>
                <h1>xs=8</h1>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={8}>
                <h1>xs=8</h1>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        </>
    );
}

export default AboutPage;
```

On the rendered page it stacks the h1 items on top of each other. Why aren't the default columns changing? I am using "@material-ui/core": "4.12.3"

Comment: Are you looking the the V5 documentation? I don't see a columns prop in V4: [Grid API](https://v4.mui.com/api/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

Your grid indeed does have 16 columns, but you are only creating 2 items inside, each spanning 8 columns.

Here's an example that renders 16 items, each spanning 1 column, into the grid:

```
export default function ColumnsGrid() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} columns={16}>
        {Array.from(Array(16)).map((_, index) => (
          <Grid item xs={1} sm={1} md={1} key={index}>
            <Item>{index + 1}</Item>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: In the React Material UI Grid documentation it says "You can change the default number of columns (12) with the columns prop." The example there changes it to 16, as I did.